# How to define a ternary operation in reactjs correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ternary-operator

I am trying to make a function that does

IF X is true
THEN call setFalse function
ELSE don't call setFalseFunction

```
    this.state = {
      X: true,
      Y: true,
      Z: true,
    };
  }

  setFalse() {

    this.setState({

      X: true ? this.setState.setFalse() : !this.setState.setFalse()),
      Y: true ? this.setState.setFalse() : !this.setState.setFalse()),
      Z: true ? this.setState.setFalse() : !this.setState.setFalse())

    });
  }
```

But that's not seem to be working, I've also tried X = true? instead of X: true?, still no luck.

Comment: Why does it need to be a ternary operator? `if (true) this.setState.setFalse();`.

Comment: `!this.setState.setFalse()` doesn't mean *"don't call setFalse"*, it means *"call setFalse then negate the result"*. Also you never refer to the current value of `X`, and if your new state depends on the old one you should use the callback form of `setState`. I'd strongly recommend reading a structured tutorial (see e.g. https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

Comment: That is not how you use `setState`. But generally you can use `&&`  - `condition && doStuff()` will call `doStuff` only when condition is truthy.

Comment: I am checking for 3 different conditions and though using and if would make it longer.

Comment: What would be the best way to achieve what I need?

Comment: it'd be helpful if you can show us the *real* code

Comment: Updated the description with the full function

Comment: If you are comparing X to true then use "==", "=" is for an assignment.

Comment: I tried == as well but it's getting udnerlined in red

Comment: it says "," expected

Comment: Doing it three times doesn't help it make any more sense. `true ? one() : two()` will **always** call `one`. Also it's not at all clear what you think `this.setState.setFalse` is going to be. If you mean `this.setFalse()` then that's going to recurse endlessly. Are you trying to set all values to false? Then why not just `setState({ X: false, Y: false, Z: false })`?

Comment: Let's stick with 1 variable for now. All I need is if value of X is true, I need to call the setFalse function, if not do nothing. The reason I am calling a setFalse function is because besides setting the value to false, I am having it perform other actions as well

Comment: But what you've shown us *is* the `setFalse` function. *"if value of X is true"* is not tested **at all**.

Comment: Oops my mistake, I need to call the setFalseResults function not setFalse.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this -> *"IF X is true THEN call setFalse function ELSE don't call setFalseFunction"*

Then you don't need the `setState` for anything, because **your not changing the state** of your variables(X,Y,Z)! You want to simply **verify if they're true** and if they are, you want to call the function `setFalse`, correct?

You can achieve that by simply doing, E.g:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    X: true,
    Y: true,
    Z: true,
  }

  setFalse() {
    console.log('I was called')
  }

  render() {
    const {X} = this.state

    return <div>{ X ? this.setFalse() : null }</div>
  }
}
```

Now, if you want to call the setFalse, and change the state of your variables, then you need to go into your function and do:

```
  setFalse() {
    console.log('I was called')

    this.setState({
      X: false,
    })
  }
```

Open your develop tools and see the state changing, got an example working [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-p0s6y)

I'd recommend you to see a little bit about **lifecycle** in React and [study it](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

[image]

Comment: @AdamKhan go for it! I hope i could help you even a litte bit! See here: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that's not have `setState()` is meant to be used, if you want a method that could make `false` all you states, you need to do the following:

```
this.state = {
  X: true,
  Y: true,
  Z: true,
};

// Change all the states to "false", without checking then
setFalse = () {
  this.setState({ X: false, Y: false, Z: false });
};
```

If what you want is to check the current value of every state, and then based on that, assign a new value, you could do:

```
setFalse = () => {
  const { X, Y, Z } = this.state;

  // If the states are "true", change them to "false"
  this.setState({ X: X ? !X : X, Y: Y ? !Y : Y, Z: Z ? !Z : Z });
};
```